# Preventing me from reading data uploaded by my users to Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, encryption

So I have an app in which the user collects the contact details of other people (like name, phone, email etc).
When the details are collected I save them in Realm on the device and to Firebase Database so that his contacts are accessible when he changes devices. 
My problem is that I can read all the details he uploads to the database and I want to prevent this from happening.

So I want only the user and no one else to be able to read the data he uploads.

So my question is: is there a way I can achieve it without encryption?
If it can't be achieved this way, then what's the easiest and best way to encrypt and decrypt those details?

I've read similar questions on SO and also tried searching articles but unfortunately I don't understand them. I have zero knowledge about encryption.

If my only option is encryption it would also be greatly appreciated if you could guide me in the right direction by providing SO answers, articles, tutorials whatever. Thanks!

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. So this question is off topic for this site. That being said, there's no need for encryption and it's unclear why you are using two different back-end databases, and why you're not using [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to only allow that user to see their data.

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry, I've only intended that question as a second additional one to my main question. So you're saying that I can deny myself access to the user data using Firebase Security Rules? Could you please explain how should I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I included the link to Firebase Rules in my original comment - it explains how rules work and provides examples as well. *If* you are the creator of the App, and created a project in your Firebase console then you would have access to your projects settings and data through the console. Other than that, you could leverage rules to provide fine-grained access to any component within the data or no access at all.

Comment: @Jay Well I've already read through that doc and set up the security rules in such a way that only the current user has access to his own data. This is all well and good, but my problem is that I, as the creator of the app, am able to read the user's data in the console. This is what I want to prevent.

Comment: There's no way to block your own access in the console - which obviously wouldn't make sense as somebody has to have access. So then you looking at encoding all of your data which can be a significant performance hit (depending on implementation). Check out [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) which works very well.

Comment: @Jay thanks for suggesting RNCryptor, I implemented it and it works perfectly. The thing I'm stuck on now is the question of where I'm supposed to store the encryption key? I have two possible solutions: storing it in the Firebase database (not really secure but at least the data is not in plain sight) or using Google KMS (I don't really want this: I don't want to complicate my backend more and it's a paid service). Is there a third way or a standard way to do this? Thanks again for reading this long comment and spending the time to answer.

Comment: This is tough. Hard coding the encryption key in the app is not generally a good idea. Storing it in Firebase is a possibility and you can use rules to lock it down to only your uid. You could of course, put it on a sticky-note and hide it under your keyboard but that's slightly un-secure as well. It's really going to depend on how you implement the encryption - as you had mentioned, you don't want to have access to the data either but if you have the key, you have access.

Comment: @Jay yes, I'm thinking along the same lines. I've looked at the privacy policies of other apps and I've found that most of them (even the big shots such as Evernote) state that they *can* access their user's content but promise that they *will not*. Storing the encryption key in Firebase would have the same effect: I *could* decrypt user content but would not see it automatically. I could state this in the policy. (I know you're not a lawyer and I'm not asking for legal advice, just looking at your profile I see that you are lightyears more experienced than me.)